# Merging columns in INNER/LEFT JOIN returns NULL values?

Tags: mysql, left-join, concatenation, inner-join

I'm facing an issue where I have several tables joined, but I need to combine the `e.url` and `f.url_new` columns. Otherwise, the result is as expected. Here is my query.

```
SELECT a.`added_date`,b.`type`,c.`action`,e.`url`,f.`url_new` 
FROM `websites_submitted_main` a
INNER JOIN `websites_submitted_type` b ON a.`type_id` = b.`type_id` 
INNER JOIN `websites_submitted_action` c ON a.`action_id` = c.`action_id`
INNER JOIN `users` d ON a.`user_id` = d.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `websites` e ON a.`url_id` = e.`id`
LEFT JOIN `websites_submitted_new` f ON a.`url_new_id` = f.`url_new_id`
WHERE a.`user_id` = 1 ORDER BY a.`added_date` DESC
```

I've tried `CONCAT`, but the column contained all `NULL` values. Here's that query.

```
SELECT a.`added_date`,b.`type`,c.`action`,CONCAT(e.`url`,f.`url_new`) AS url 
FROM `websites_submitted_main` a
INNER JOIN `websites_submitted_type` b ON a.`type_id` = b.`type_id` 
INNER JOIN `websites_submitted_action` c ON a.`action_id` = c.`action_id`
INNER JOIN `users` d ON a.`user_id` = d.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `websites` e ON a.`url_id` = e.`id`
LEFT JOIN `websites_submitted_new` f ON a.`url_new_id` = f.`url_new_id`
WHERE a.`user_id` = 1 ORDER BY a.`added_date` DESC
```

Is there a minor modification I can make to this query to merge these columns?

Comment: I would say CONCAT should work, but have you tried `e.url || f.url_new`?

Comment: Still returns `NULL` values in the `url` column :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [CONCAT_WS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead of `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT  `CONCAT_WS(' ',e.url, f.url_new )` ....
```

`CONCAT_WS()` will concatenate the values if the values are not null.

From the manual of [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

> CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

```
SELECT a.`added_date`,b.`type`,c.`action`,CONCAT_WS("", e.`url`,f.`url_new`) AS url 
FROM `websites_submitted_main` a
INNER JOIN `websites_submitted_type` b ON a.`type_id` = b.`type_id` 
INNER JOIN `websites_submitted_action` c ON a.`action_id` = c.`action_id`
INNER JOIN `users` d ON a.`user_id` = d.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `websites` e ON a.`url_id` = e.`id`
LEFT JOIN `websites_submitted_new` f ON a.`url_new_id` = f.`url_new_id`
WHERE a.`user_id` = 1 ORDER BY a.`added_date` DESC
```

Comment: CONCAT() will return null if any argument is null. CONCAT_WS() ignores the null values and moves on to the next argument